# CF10 mod_jk.so won't load with RHEL 5.6 and Apache httpd 2.2.3

Tags: apache, tomcat, coldfusion, mod-jk, rhel

Does anyone have a solution to this...  Running RHEL 5.6, with Apache httpd 2.2.3-65.el5_8 and get this error when trying to start the webserver:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 445 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/httpd/conf/mod_jk.conf: Cannot load /data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so into server: /data/cf10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so: undefined symbol: ap_get_server_description

I've looked all over Google, and there are some recommendations to compile my own connector, but I need the one from Adobe for CF10.   Also the adobe site lists CF10 compatibility w/ Apache HTTPD 2.2.21, well with RedHat Enterprise they don't move the version number up, it gets reverse patched in the app repo.... ANY help would be awesome.

We are 50 days from going live with CF10 (or planning to), and really could use some help on getting this issue resolved.

In response to one of the posters here, I have indeed verified I'm using the x64 connector in my x64 OS based system.

---

Response from Adobe w/ SOLUTION!

Here's the response and resolution: You may download the connector from the following “RHEL_mod_jk.zip” web-link at:
http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/rhel-connector-configuration.html

Please note that you may proceed with the installation choosing not to configure the web server initially. Once CF is installed you may proceed to create the connector using the wsconfig tool at
\ColdFusion10\cfusion\runtime\bin

Find the instructions at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fd9.html
Once the connector is in place you may simply navigate to \ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\ folder and replace the mod_jk.so file with downloaded copy and restart Apache.

Comment: Sorry, just been through wsconfig.jar and there's no longer the source anywhere, just pre-built connectors. I'd raise it with Adobe. I noticed that there are 32 and 64-bit connectors present in wsconfig.jar\connectors\apache\. Do you have the right one for your architecture?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming. This is a server question, so try [SF].

Comment: Thanks, Peter.... I'll do that.

Comment: Contacted adobe, and they provided us with a x64 version of mod_jk.so which is what was the issue.  They also provided us with step by step instructions on how to install using this modified version.  Response and resolution have been appended to original for future searchers.

Comment: Jaazu, you should put the response as an answer and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response from Adobe w/ SOLUTION!

Here's the response and resolution: You may download the connector from the following “RHEL_mod_jk.zip” web-link at: http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/rhel-connector-configuration.html

Please note that you may proceed with the installation choosing not to configure the web server initially. Once CF is installed you may proceed to create the connector using the wsconfig tool at \ColdFusion10\cfusion\runtime\bin

Find the instructions at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fd9.html Once the connector is in place you may simply navigate to \ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig\ folder and replace the mod_jk.so file with downloaded copy and restart Apache.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add to the discussion my experience with install issues of CF. I've bumped up on two common issues with installing CF, the problems has been so consistent that I wrote a short "how to" blogpost so I wouldn't forget the next time I needed to deploy another server. While my blog post addresses CF 10 and Cent OS 6.4, this method has always worked as far back as I can remember (eg: CF 8)

http://www.greenvalleyconsulting.org/2013/05/16/installation-problem-coldfusion-10-and-centos-6-x/